# how to deploy the custom model in amazon sageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am newbie to AWS sagemaker, I am trying to  deploy the time series custom  lstm model in sagemaker , please help me out and  how to perpare the script mode.
this  my script file **timer_series.py** code.

```
import sagemaker
import boto3
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


if __name__ =='__main__':

    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=72)
    parser.add_argument('--n_train_hours', type=int, default=24*365*2)
    parser.add_argument('--n_validation_hours', type=int, default=24*365*4)

    # input data and model directories
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str)

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    train_dataset_dir = os.environ.get('SM_INPUT_DIR') + '/data/training/' 
    output_model_dir = os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR')
    output_object_dir = os.environ.get('SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR')

    epochs = args.epochs
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    input_data = {args.input_data}
    dataset = read_csv( train_dataset_dir + 'dataset.csv', header=0, index_col='Date')
    dataset.sort_index(inplace=True)
    train = dataset.iloc[:109]
    test= dataset.iloc[109:]  
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_train = scaler.fit_transform(train)
    scaled_test=scaler.fit_transform(test)
    n_input = 12
    n_feature = 1

    train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=n_input, batch_size=1)

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(128,activation = 'relu', input_shape= (n_input, n_feature), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    history =model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=50, batch_size=1,verbose=1)

# Get a SageMaker-compatible role used by this Notebook Instance.
    role = get_execution_role()
    with open(output_model_dir + '/history.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(history.history, f)
    #Save the Scaler
    dump(scaler, output_model_dir + '/scaler.model', protocol=2) 
    #Save the trained model and weights
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open(output_model_dir + "/model.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    model.save_weights(output_model_dir + "/model.h5")
```

here it showing some error:

```
 train_instance_type = "ml.m4.xlarg"

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='time_series.py', role=get_execution_role(),
                          train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
                          framework_version='1.12', py_version='py3', script_mode=True,
                          output_path = 's3://' + s3Bucket, base_job_name = "sales-forecasting-lstm",
                         hyperparameters={'batch_size': 2,
                                           'epochs': 50})

tf_estimator.fit(uploaded_data_path)
```

Here I got the error. what this error , I didn't understand this error.

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sales-forecasting-lstm-2020-04-13-10-17-34-919: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/usr/bin/python time_series.py --batch_size 2 --epochs 50 --model_dir s3://sagemaker12/sales-forecasting-lstm-2020-04-13-10-17-34-919/model"

​
```

Hi, I am newbie to AWS sagemaker, I am trying to  deploy the time series custom  lstm model in sagemaker , please help me out and  how to perpare the script mode , python script  for deployment.
this  my script file **timer_series.py** code.

```
import sagemaker
import boto3
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


if __name__ =='__main__':

    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=50)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=72)
    parser.add_argument('--n_train_hours', type=int, default=24*365*2)
    parser.add_argument('--n_validation_hours', type=int, default=24*365*4)

    # input data and model directories
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str)

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    train_dataset_dir = os.environ.get('SM_INPUT_DIR') + '/data/training/' 
    output_model_dir = os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR')
    output_object_dir = os.environ.get('SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR')

    epochs = args.epochs
    batch_size = args.batch_size
    input_data = {args.input_data}
    dataset = read_csv( input_data + 'dataset.csv', header=0, index_col='Date')
    dataset.sort_index(inplace=True)
    train = dataset.iloc[:109]
    test= dataset.iloc[109:]  
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_train = scaler.fit_transform(train)
    scaled_test=scaler.fit_transform(test)
    n_input = 12
    n_feature = 1

    train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train,scaled_train,length=n_input, batch_size=1)

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(128,activation = 'relu', input_shape= (n_input, n_feature), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    history =model.fit_generator(train_generator,epochs=50, batch_size=1,verbose=1)

# Get a SageMaker-compatible role used by this Notebook Instance.
    role = get_execution_role()
    with open(output_model_dir + '/history.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(history.history, f)
    #Save the Scaler
    dump(scaler, output_model_dir + '/scaler.model', protocol=2) 
    #Save the trained model and weights
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open(output_model_dir + "/model.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    model.save_weights(output_model_dir + "/model.h5")
```

here it showing some error:

```
 train_instance_type = "ml.m4.xlarg"

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='time_series.py', role=get_execution_role(),
                          train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type=train_instance_type,
                          framework_version='1.12', py_version='py3', script_mode=True,
                          output_path = 's3://' + s3Bucket, base_job_name = "sales-forecasting-lstm",
                         hyperparameters={'batch_size': 2,
                                           'epochs': 50})

tf_estimator.fit(uploaded_data_path)
```

Here I got the error. what this error , I didn't understand this error.

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job sales-forecasting-lstm-2020-04-13-10-17-34-919: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/usr/bin/python time_series.py --batch_size 2 --epochs 50 --model_dir s3://sagemaker12/sales-forecasting-lstm-2020-04-13-10-17-34-919/model"

​
```

Comment: can you check in Cloudwatch or in the notebook the full error log? this line just says that the script errored, but you need to see the error to be able to debug it

Comment: Hi Olivier , I saw the Cloud watch logs file , but  It is  showing  same error. I want to known one thing ..is it script error or packages version  error. please help me how to fix it  i was struggling  with this last 3 days,

Comment: cloudwatch is empty? no python error code? Can you try running locally (train_instance_type='local') and report all the logs you see?

Comment: No i  am saying  I got the same errors,above  error. check this

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time_series.py", line 5, in <module>
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 117, in __init__
    sagemaker_runtime_client=sagemaker_runtime_client,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 131, in _initialize
    "Must setup local AWS configuration with a region supported by SageMaker."

10:08:01

Comment: ValueError: Must setup local AWS configuration with a region supported by SageMaker.
ValueError: Must setup local AWS configuration with a region supported by SageMaker.

10:08:01
2020-04-17 10:08:00,972 sagemaker-containers ERROR ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/usr/bin/python3 time_series.py --batch_size 1 --epochs 50 --model_dir s3://sagemaker12/sales-forecasting-lstm-2020-04-17-09-43-48-764/model"
Command "/usr/bin/python3 time_series.py --batch_size 1 --epochs 50 --model_dir s3://sagemaker12/sales-forecasting-lstm-2020-04-17-09-43-48-764/model"

Comment: 2020-04-17 10:08:00,972 sagemaker-containers ERROR    ExecuteUserScriptError:

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change  timer_series.py cahnnels to your s3 paths, you do not have to add the plus sign on your train_dataset_dir and add sagemaker specific arguments as:

`parser.add_argument('--output-data-dir', type=str, default='s3://bucket_name/folder_name/output')`

Line above for directions on where your output data should be stored. However that is something you have to specify when calling the batch transform function. Otherwise would store it in default bucket.
Second in order to debug , and being able to help you, you would have to take a look at CloudWatch for that specific training job to better understand what is failing on your script: time_series.py. I suppose is a problem with the specifications and reading of your training data.